# Testing if two models have a significant different forecast (error)

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, model-selection

I have two different models which estimate a continuous variable $X$ depending on N categorial covariates $V_i$.

Is there a way to test if both models produce significantly different results? I could test for differences of their mean, median, variance, and distribution. However, how can I account for the categorial covariates?

If all covariates $V_i$ are regarded there is only one forecast value for each combination of the covariates' values. Hence there is no distribution. What can I test here - MSE/RMSE, MAE? Can I test these measures statistically at all? There is a question on [how to compare the accuracy of two different models using statistical significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27228/how-to-compare-the-accuracy-of-two-different-models-using-statistical-significan) which is unfortunately unanswered.

In addition the observered value for each combination of the N categorial variables is known. Does it make a difference to test the forecast error instead of the forcast value? A related question on the [comparison of two error distributions to determine “goodness of fit”](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78285/comparison-of-two-error-distributions-to-determine-goodness-of-fit) is answered. However, the answer assumes an error estimate $\sigma_i$ for the experimentally measured values which correspond to my observed values. I do not have such an estimation because my observed values are simple countings of how often a covariate combination is observed in the whole population.

To make my problem clear: I can calculate the error $E$ for each of the combination of the covariates' values. Afterwards I could test if $E_1$ and $E_2$ of the models $M_1$ and $M_1$ are different with respect to their mean, median, variance, and distribution. However, what if both models have the same forecast errors, but in very different combinations of the covariates' values?